# What am I missing in my Express app when trying to render React SSR?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I'm going nuts over this issue. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

My setup is the following:

- Express server created with Express Generator
- React app created with CRA

I would like to be able to do SSR for my React scripts.

Folder structure is like this:

```
src/
    bin/
        www
    routes/
        index.js
    app.js
    .babelrc
    client/ (React app files)
        src/
            App.js
```

I start the Express server using the following script in my package.json:

```
nodemon --exec babel-node ./src/bin/www
```

I try to render a React component in `routes/index.js` by doing the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import App from '../client/src/App';
...
```

`.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

And in the file `/bin/www` I've put the following (at the top):

```
require("@babel/register")({
    presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
})
...
```

But all I can get out is.....

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

which points to:

```
/srv/app/customer-server/src/client/src/App.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

What am I missing here? Am I doing the impossible for this kind of setup?

Thank you

Comment: What is the content of app.js inside root/src folder. I mean what is it used for?

Comment: @Rishabh thata where I continue setup express with routes etc

Comment: What `package.json` files do you have and where in the directory structure are they?

Comment: @loganfsmyth it is in the ”src” folder for the server, and then there is a package.json in the client/src server as well for the React app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I was using Docker with mounted volumes which was causing the error, it was all working fine after I got that figured out.